# Get disk usage (>90%) from metricbeats system module

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I'm trying to check if current disk usage exceeds 90% for each host. I've ended up with such query:

```
GET /metricbeat-2017.04.18/_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists" : { "field" : "system.fsstat.total_size" }
  },
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "by_hostname": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "beat.hostname",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "newst_fsstat": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [{"@timestamp": {"order": "desc"}}],
            "size" : 1
          }
        },
        "total_size": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "system.fsstat.total_size.total"
          }
        },
        "used_size": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "system.fsstat.total_size.used"
          }
        },
        "disk_usage_percentage": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "total": "total_size",
              "used": "used_size"
            },
            "script": "params.used / params.total * 100"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I cannot put next aggs in top_hists, and thus total_size and used_size are sum of every docs.

Also, I'm having trouble to filter disk_usage_percentage to include only those > 90%.

Can you help with such query?